# Using cut in linux for a file

Tags: linux

I want to use space as a delimiter with the cut command for all the entries in my file. Basically my file has a single column with each row looking something like this:

3 0000000000000o0

I want to separate the 3 from the remaining data using cut.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

In cut, -d is used to specify the delimiter and -f used to specify the field required. Below command should output what you require.

`cut -d' ' -f1 yourfilename`